# How can I use Jackson to deserialize "flat" JSON into complex Java objects based solely on patterns in the names of the keys?

Tags: java, jackson

I am receiving JSON from a 3rd party, which I cannot control. Assume I have the following Java classes:

```
class Student {
    String id;
    Name name;
    List<Course> courses;
}

class Name {
    String first;
    String middle;
    String last;
}

class Course {
    String subject;
    String number;
}
```

I would expect the JSON for a list of Students to look something like this:

```
{
  "students":[
    {
      "id":"00123",
      "name":{
        "first":"John",
        "middle":"Quincy",
        "last":"Adams"
      },
      "courses":[
        {
          "subject":"MATH",
          "number":"101"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the JSON I am receiving is in a completely "flat" format (no nested objects). All of the data is "associated" through patterns in the names of the keys. For example:

```
{
  "student_1_ID_groupA": "00123",
  "name_1_StudentID_groupA": "00123"
  "name_1_FirstName_groupA": "John",
  "name_1_MiddleName_groupA": "Quincy",
  "name_1_LastName_groupA": "Adams",
  "course_1_StudentID_groupA": "00123",
  "course_1_Subject_groupA": "MATH",
  "course_1_Number_groupA": "101",

  "student_2_ID_groupA": "00456",
  "name_2_StudentID_groupA": "00456"
  "name_2_FirstName_groupA": "Edgar",
  "name_2_MiddleName_groupA": "Allen",
  "name_2_LastName_groupA": "Poe",
  "course_2_StudentID_groupA": "00456",
  "course_2_Subject_groupA": "LIT",
  "course_2_Number_groupA": "201",

  "student_1_ID_groupB": "00789",
  "name_1_StudentID_groupB": "00789"
  "name_1_FirstName_groupB": "Martin",
  "name_1_MiddleName_groupB": "Luther",
  "name_1_LastName_groupB": "King",
  "course_1_StudentID_groupB": "00789",
  "course_1_Subject_groupB": "BIO",
  "course_1_Number_groupB": "120",
  "course_2_StudentID_groupB": "00789",
  "course_2_Subject_groupB": "CHEM",
  "course_2_Number_groupB": "120",
}
```

The key names are made up of four parts, which could easily be parsed with regex:

1. The object type
2. A numeric identifier
3. The field name
4. A group

The objects are uniquely identified by combining their numeric identifier and their group. Student `1` from `groupA` is a different object than Student `1` from `groupB`. Similarly, Student `1` from `groupA` is a different object than Student `2` from `groupA`.

Ultimately, I need to deserialze this JSON into a list of students.

```
List<Student> students; // contains all Students defined above
```

I've tried to find examples of solving a similar problem, but with no luck. I must admit, I am at a loss for where to start. I know Jackson supports a lot of customization, like custom deserializers. However, I would greatly appreciate if somebody could let me know if such a task is even possible using Jackson, and if it is, provide some pointers to get started.

Comment: I switched from Jackson to GSon because of similar troubles. Maybe worth giving it a try?